# How the make the search list shorter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: t short]

How to make the search result show like much shorter like 4 row instead of all and extending to the bottom?

Here is my code:

```
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
```

css code:

```
#myUL li a {
  transform: translate(270px,-1400px); 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 28%;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
```

Rest of the code:

```
var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
// hilde the list by default
UL.style.display = "none";
var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

// show the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("focus",  function(){
    // UL.style.display = "block";
});

// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){

});


function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    // if the input is empty hide the list
    if(filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
    } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
    }
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");   
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
     if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) { 
        li[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
```

Please help me I'm trying to solve this for a few hours now :(
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whre are you getting the search results from?

Comment: The list inside the code. Something like this:<li><a href="#"> CASCO EDUCATIONAL SUPPLY PTE LTD 01-02 </a></li>

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var limit = 4;    
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < li.length && j < limit; i++) {
```

and in the block where there's a match, this

```
// This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    li[i].style.display = "";
    j++;
} else {
```

The loop will terminate when you've made 4 matches

Comment: It dosen't work tho but I had updated with my css code could that be a problem which cause this?

Comment: @Dr.Joben Can you post the part of the code relevant to populating the search results? The problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: I might found the problem. `        ul.style.display = "block";` which will show  the whole list. How can I recode it to show only 4?

Comment: Sorry to trouble you but where do I put the '        li[i].style.display = "";
j++;' in which part of my code? I had updated my full script code above. I'm sorry if I'm bothering you but I thank you so much for your help and time :)